# What happened to the JGoodies binding tutorial code?

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

I want to learn how to use JGoodies binding (since beans binding seems dead in the water, and so does its fork). the JGoosides binding docs refer to the tutorial source code, but this code is not available in the latest (2.5) distribution.

After looking though previous distribution versions is seems the tutorial code was dropped between 2.0.6 and 2.1.0

Am I to understand that the tutorial is outdated?
if so, is there an up-to-date tutorial distribution somewhere that I just managed to miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same exact question and it took me quite awhile to find an answer. You are correct in that the latest version (2.5) does not contain the tutorial code. However, the old tutorial code (v2.06) is an extremely good starting point, and will teach you the fundamentals. (At least it did for me.)

From browsing the [Release Notes](http://www.jgoodies.com/download/libraries/binding/RELEASE-NOTES.txt) there are a few significant changes between 2.06 and 2.5 with the com.jgoodies.binding.binder package being the largest. (Interestingly the document doesn't specifically mention that the tutorial was removed...)

The only gotcha with the old tutorial code:

```
com.jgoodies.binding.list.ArrayListModel
com.jgoodies.binding.list.ObservableList
```

have been replaced by:

```
com.jgoodies.common.collect.ArrayListModel
com.jgoodies.common.collect.ObservableList
```

There are also several tutorials online which are quite good, however, note that they are based on the extremely old v1.0. Again though, the principals and concepts are the same.

1. [JGoodies: Understanding Binding - Part 1](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17672)
2. [JGoodies: Understanding Binding - Part 2](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17707)
3. [JGoodies: Understanding Binding - Part 3](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17728)
4. [JGoodies: Understanding Binding - Part 4](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17788.html)
5. [Introduction to JGoodies Binding](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJun2005.html)

Answer (score 4):

JGoodies removed the files linked below. However, I believe the tutorials are still available in the Java 1.4 libraries in the new [archives](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/archive/).

Also, Karsten Lentzsch is building a new Showcase app that will have all the tutorial sources. It may be available in July.

---

Old post:

> Reading the tutorial code is probably the best way to learn JGoodies,
>   even though it's outdated. You can still get them from the
>   [archives](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/archive/):
>
> http://www.jgoodies.com/download/libraries/binding/binding-1_5_0.zip
>
> http://www.jgoodies.com/download/libraries/validation/validation-1_4_0.zip
>
> http://www.jgoodies.com/download/libraries/forms/forms-1_3_0.zip

Comment: The Archives seems to be gone :(

Answer (score 2):

I've also been looking for the tutorial code.

It's available in the Showcase app (latest version at time of writing this is 1.6.6).

http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/demos/

Open the Showcase app in Java WebStart.  You may need to add a security exception for http://www.jgoodies.com in your Java settings to allow the app to run.

Once you've opened the demo, you can access the source code by clicking on the "Show details" button on the top right corner of the window.

I hope this helps.[image: JGoodies Showcase App 1.6.6]