# Jgoodies demo source code not available

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

In the JGoodies download page at http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/demos/ they say

"The Showcase provides tutorial examples including sources for the Binding, Forms, and Validation."

however they only allow some .jnlp to be web started.

Where are the showcases source code for the BookFinder, Looks Demo, Metamorphosis, Showcase and Skeleton??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find this question: [what happened to the jgoodies binding tutorial code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975879/what-happened-to-the-jgoodies-binding-tutorial-code/9779064#9779064)
The files seem to be gone. But someone there mentions Karsten Lentzsch, who apparently was in the process of moving/rewriting the code.
A Google search for his name sent me to http://markmail.org/message/kzanosxsys5iawvx#query:+page:1+mid:6at2awzeogsx6xlp+state:results where you can maybe get his email address, or see the mailing list to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

The sources for the demos are only available to customers.

The Showcase itself contains sources for the demonstrated features, including tutorial sources for the Binding, Forms, Validation, etc.